# Python - Continue Code Execution After Popping Up MsgBox?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I'm fairly new to Python.  Here's a script I have that gathers info from our MySQL server hosting our Helpdesk tickets, and will pop up a message box (using EasyGUI's "msgbox()" function) whenever a new ticket arrives.

The issue is that I want my program to continue processing after the popup, regardless of whether the user clicks "OK" or not, even if that means message boxes could keep popping up over each other and must be dismissed one by one; that would be fine with me.

I looked into threading, and either it doesn't work or I did something wrong and need a good guide.  Here's my code:

```
import MySQLdb
import time
from easygui import *

# Connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="MySQL.MyDomain.com", user="user", passwd="pass", db="db")
cursor = db.cursor()

# Before-and-after arrays to compare; A change means a new ticket arrived
IDarray = ([0,0,0])
IDarray_prev = ([0,0,0])

# Compare the latest 3 tickets since more than 1 may arrive in my time interval
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM Tickets ORDER BY id DESC limit 3;")
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
   row = cursor.fetchone()
   for num in row:
      IDarray_prev[x] = int(num)
cursor.close()
db.commit()

while 1:
   cursor = db.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM Tickets ORDER BY id DESC limit 3;")

   numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
   for x in range(0,numrows):
      row = cursor.fetchone()
      for num in row:
         IDarray[x] = int(num)

   if(IDarray != IDarray_prev): 
      cursor.execute("SELECT Subject FROM Tickets ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;")
      subject = cursor.fetchone()
      for line in subject:
         # -----------------------------------------
         # STACKOVERFLOW, HERE IS THE MSGBOX LINE!!!
         # -----------------------------------------
         msgbox("A new ticket has arrived:\n"+line)

   # My time interval -- Checks the database every 8 seconds:
   time.sleep(8)
   IDarray_prev = IDarray[:]
   cursor.close()
   db.commit()
```

Comment: There's no threading in your example

Comment: What you need is a modeless (as opposed to modal) dialog. Most graphics packages offer this option, but a quick glance at the easyGUI docs didn't seem to indicate that possibility.

Comment: @intra I tried threading, it didn't work, so I took it out.

Comment: @jpm I will search around for a Python GUI package that offers modeless dialogs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Python GTK+](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html)

It offers non-modal using

```
set_modal(False)
```

Comment: I keep running into too many ImportErrors... Now I'm just spending too much time (which equals money) on something so stupid and simple.  I'm settling with os.system("msg console (%s) % message") even though this is modal.